# Trying to program two buttons to appear when the player in my game dies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, syntax

I am writing to ask for some assistance please. I am trying to program two buttons a Main menu and Exit button in my game to appear only when my player dies. I have been trying to define the gameobject list with,

GameManager Script.

```
//Awake is always called before any Start functions
void Awake()
{
    //Check if instance already exists
    if (instance == null)

        //if not, set instance to this
        instance = this;

    //If instance already exists and it's not this:
    else if (instance != this)

        //Then destroy this. This enforces our singleton pattern, meaning there can only ever be one instance of a GameManager.
        Destroy(gameObject);

    //Sets this to not be destroyed when reloading scene
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    //Assign enemies to a new List of Enemy objects.
    enemies = new List<Enemy>();

    //Get a component reference to the attached BoardManager script
    boardScript = GetComponent<BoardManager>();

    //Call the InitGame function to initialize the first level 
    //InitGame();
}

// TODO: Uncommented Code
/// <summary>
/// Called when the level / scene has finished loading
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scene"></param>
/// <param name="mode"></param>
void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    // Don't initialize game on main menu. That would be silly
    if (scene.buildIndex > 0)
    {
        InitGame();
    }

    level++; // Increment after we have loaded level. Might be a better place to put this
}

// TODO: Uncomemnted code
void OnEnable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnLevelFinishedLoading;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnLevelFinishedLoading;
}

//Initializes the game for each level.
void InitGame()
{
    //While doingSetup is true the player can't move, prevent player from moving while title card is up.
    doingSetup = true;

    //Get a reference to our image LevelImage by finding it by name.
    levelImage = GameObject.Find("LevelImage");

    //Get a reference to our text LevelText's text component by finding it by name and calling GetComponent.
    levelText = GameObject.Find("LevelText").GetComponent<Text>();

    //Set the text of levelText to the string "Day" and append the current level number.
    levelText.text = "Day " + level;

    //Set levelImage to active blocking player's view of the game board during setup.
    levelImage.SetActive(true);

    //Call the HideLevelImage function with a delay in seconds of levelStartDelay.
    Invoke("HideLevelImage", levelStartDelay);

    //Clear any Enemy objects in our List to prepare for next level.
    enemies.Clear();

    //Call the SetupScene function of the BoardManager script, pass it current level number.
    boardScript.SetupScene(level);

    // TODO: Removed initGame() from here. No need to call it twice
}

//Hides black image used between levels
void HideLevelImage()
{
    //Disable the levelImage gameObject.
    levelImage.SetActive(false);

    //Set doingSetup to false allowing player to move again.
    doingSetup = false;
}

//Update is called every frame.
void Update()
{
    //Check that playersTurn or enemiesMoving or doingSetup are not currently true.
    if (playersTurn || enemiesMoving || doingSetup)

        //If any of these are true, return and do not start MoveEnemies.
        return;

    //Start moving enemies.
    StartCoroutine(MoveEnemies());
}

//Call this to add the passed in Enemy to the List of Enemy objects.
public void AddEnemyToList(Enemy script)
{
    //Add Enemy to List enemies.
    enemies.Add(script);
}

public void ShowButtons()
{
    foreach (var Button in buttons)
    {
        var gameOver = GetComponent<Exit2>();
        Button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

//GameOver is called when the player reaches 0 food points
public void GameOver()
{
    //Set levelText to display number of levels passed and game over message
    levelText.text = "After " + level + " days, you starved.";

    //Shows buttons on player's death.
    var gameOver = GetComponent<Exit2>();
    gameOver.ShowButtons("Main menu 2", "Exit2");

    //Enable black background image gameObject.
    levelImage.SetActive(true);

    //Disable this GameManager.
    enabled = false;
}

//Coroutine to move enemies in sequence.
IEnumerator MoveEnemies()
{
    //While enemiesMoving is true player is unable to move.
    enemiesMoving = true;

    //Wait for turnDelay seconds, defaults to .1 (100 ms).
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);

    //If there are no enemies spawned (IE in first level):
    if (enemies.Count == 0)
    {
        //Wait for turnDelay seconds between moves, replaces delay caused by enemies moving when there are none.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
    }

    //Loop through List of Enemy objects.
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
    {
        //Call the MoveEnemy function of Enemy at index i in the enemies List.
        enemies[i].MoveEnemy();

        //Wait for Enemy's moveTime before moving next Enemy, 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemies[i].moveTime);
    }
    //Once Enemies are done moving, set playersTurn to true so player can move.
    playersTurn = true;

    //Enemies are done moving, set enemiesMoving to false.
    enemiesMoving = false;
}

void Awake()
{
    // Get the buttons
    menuButtonList();
    //buttons = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();

    // Disable them
    HideButtons();
}

public void HideButtons()
{
    foreach (var Button in buttons)
    {
        Button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void LoadByIndex(int sceneIndex)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
}

public void Quit()
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
    Application.Quit();
#endif
}
```

I just want to make it so in my `GameManager` script under `GameOver` function is called the two buttons appear with what s already defined in the game PLEASE CHECK the lines in `GameManager` 162-194 and all of `Exit2`.

Comment: Can you show us some code you used when you tried solving it yourself? What you posted is all from a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need a Canvas. Then you create the two buttons inside the canvas. Have a reference to the instance of this canvas in your GameManager script.

Deactivate it via .SetActive(false) when the game starts, then Activate it again when the GameOver happens via .SetActive(true).

Add 2 methods to the GameManager script, one for Exit and one for MainMenu. And have the two buttons you created have their OnClick event trigger those 2 methods.